# Are exception descriptions from exception::what() standarized for standard exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, standards

For standardized exceptions like `std::bad_alloc`, is the string returned by `exception::what()` expected to be the same across compilers?

For example, several compilers I've worked with all return `bad allocation` for `bad_alloc::what()`.  Is there some reason a more descriptive string such as `Memory allocation failure` isn't returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the string returned by `exception::what()` expected to be the same across compilers?

**No, this isn't standardised.**

Taking your example of `bad_alloc`:

> `[C++11: 18.6.2.1/5]:` **`virtual const char* what() const noexcept;`**
>
> *Returns:* An implementation-defined NTBS.

<sup>(NTBS means "null-terminated byte string"; it's the "implementation-defined" that you care about.)</sup>

At best, this pattern is found in all the standard exception definitions.

---

> Is there some reason a more descriptive string such as Memory allocation failure isn't returned?

Probably because it's longer, and in fact *not* more descriptive. A verbose string like "Memory allocation failure" is pretty needless; a short string that provides *the information* can always be expanded to be more human-friendly, in calling code.

Comment: Well, how is "Memory allocation failure" not more descriptive? It's certainly easier to understand than "bad allocation".

Comment: @DragonLord: I don't see why?

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard, it's all down to the implementation of the C++ runtime.